# Can I flash a PC Radeon 5870 for use in a Mac Pro?

Tags: mac-pro, gpu

I have a Mid-2010 Mac Pro, Single CPU, [MC560LL/A](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP589). It's equipped with the Apple-provided Radeon 5770.

However, I have a Radeon 5870 from my old PC lying around. I know I can't directly use it, but I wonder if there's a way to flash it to work with the Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes you can.](http://netkas.org/?p=503) Netkas has a ROM at that link that works for 5870s.

You might also get by without flashing by going the Hackintosh route and [adding some kexts](http://www.kexts.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=868)

Comment: Okay, Netkas is definitely the place to go. However, I learned that not all 5870 can be flashed (to support EFI in order to show a picture before the OS boots). Oh well, the card was lying around anyway, doesn't matter that it's bricked now. This thread is super helpful: http://forum.netkas.org/index.php?topic=692.0 - but really, if the ROM doesn't have 2 MCuC section after following the steps, it's not possible to add EFI.